# Angular 2+ and error with class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have very strange error, let me explain. I have simple ts class

```
export class Issue {

  constructor(
    public date: string,
    public title: string,
    public open: boolean,
  ) {}
}
```

Next in my component I simply export that class, and create issues array. I have create function and for example print data of issue. I'm getting error  Property 'open' does not exist on type 'Issue'.

```
 changeIssueStatus(issue: Issue): void {
   console.log(issue.date);  // It will print it correctly
   console.log(issue.title); // It will print it correctly
   console.log(issue.open);  // gives an error
 }
```

how is it caused?

Comment: Hi, just remove the comma ',' after 'public open:boolean' ?

Comment: It works with the code you provide: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Issue%20%7B%0D%0A%09constructor(%0D%0A%09%09public%20date%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%09%09public%20title%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%09%09public%20open%3A%20boolean%2C%0D%0A%09)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afunction%20changeIssueStatus(issue%3A%20Issue)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(issue.date)%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20It%20will%20print%20it%20correctly%0D%0A%09console.log(issue.title)%3B%20%2F%2F%20It%20will%20print%20it%20correctly%0D%0A%09console.log(issue.open)%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20gives%20an%20error%0D%0A%7D

Comment: nothing changes :/

Comment: I'll try to reset my ng serve

Comment: Yes it should work now.

Comment: reset work for everything...

Comment: I am adding this to solution so you can tick it as answer :)